# using jquery for submiting uniq form between multiple forms

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My page consists of multiple forms. I want to use `<a>` element (not submit button) to submit a form using jquery. for generating form ID Im using GUID. is there any better way ? do I need to assign formId ?

```
    <% Guid formId = Guid.NewGuid();
using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id =formId.ToString() }))
{
 <a href="#" onclick="$('form#<%= formId.ToString() %>').submit(); return false;">
Submit 
</a>
  <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there any better way ?

Seriously? Use a submit button to submit HTML forms. This is the only semantically correct way to do it:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller")) { %>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<% } %>
```

Or you could also use an image submit button and make it look like an anchor:

```
<input type="image" alt="Submit" src="submit.png" />
```

Comment: I need to use "a" element not input or image button.

Comment: @Reza, believe me you don't. You will end up with ugly, semantically incorrect and most importantly nonfunctional application if the user has javascript disabled.

Comment: maybe I need to use input type submit and do some css tick to look like a link

Comment: @Reza, exactly, that would be far better way.